# AngularJS Expression is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, oop

I have a controller which looks like that:

```
app.controller('DealCtrl', function($scope, Deals) {
    Deals.all().then(function (deals) {
        $scope.deals = deals;
        console.log($scope.deals);
    });
});
```

And a services.js like this:

```
var app = angular.module('starter.services', []);

app.factory('Deals', function($http) {
    function getDeals() {
        return $http.get('http://www.domain.com/library/fct.get_deals.php')
        .success(function (data) {
            var deals = data;
            return deals;
        })
        .error(function(err){
      });
  }

  return {
    all: function() {
        return getDeals();
    },
    get: function(keyID) {
        //...
    }
  }
});
```

It gets an object from my server with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    category: "...",
    title: "...",
    ...
  },
  { ... }
]
```

The problem is, I'm not able to output the `title` attribute in my `index.html`. I want to do it in the following manner:

```
...
<ion-content ng-repeat="deal in deals">
  <div class="list card">

    <div class="item item-avatar">
      <img src="img.jpg">
      <h2>{{deal.title}}</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</ion-content>
...
```

It just displays nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you're waiting for a .then after your .all() but you haven't wired up your getDeals to work like that, here's how you would do it:

```
app.factory('Deals', function($http, $q) {
    function getDeals() {
        var myPromise = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://www.domain.com/library/fct.get_deals.php')
            .success(function (data) {
                var deals = data;
                myPromise.resolve(deals);
            })
            .error(function(err){
                myPrmoise.reject();
            });
        return myPromise.promise;
    }

    return {
        all: function() {
            return getDeals();
        },
        get: function(keyID) {
            return restaurants[keyID];
        }
    }
});
```